# have 2 C files which I need to link with the compiler

Tags: c, linux, informix, 4gl, genero

So I finally cleared all the errors and warnings on the C files, and proceeded to link them.
I have 2 C files which I need to link with the compiler.

```
et5ibwqm0.c intfac_fl.c
```

The compile command I was provided:

```
gcc -shared -o et5stcklib.so et5ibwqm0.o intfac_fl.o -L$FGLDIR/lib
```

Doesn't work, I get this error:

```
et5ibwqm0.o: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Try the "file" command to see what it reports on `et51bwqm0.o` and `intfac_fl.o`.  Also, it would help to see the commands used to compile them.

Comment: The compiler compiles, the **linker** ...

Comment: @Olaf The `gcc` command hides the distinction, since it figures out from the options whether it should compile or link.

Comment: @Barmar: I know. It is actually a "driver" for the correct underlying tools (compiler, assembler, linker, etc. Yet it is not the **compiler**. Anyway, we need more information.

Comment: Have you tried purging all `.o` files in the compilation directory?

Comment: @szczurcio Why would that be necessary? He doesn't have `*.o` in the command, so it's not going to look at the other files.

Comment: Turns out it was just a missing -m32 specifier which caused the compiler to reject one of the objects

Comment: @Barmar I meant deleting all object files to force recompilation - if `et5ibwqm0.o` is reported as corrupt by `ld`, the first thing I'd do is remove it and have the compiler regenerate it to see if the error persists. As for purging all `.o` files, well, if that one is corrupt, chances are some others will be too.

Comment: The problem is probably that he's not compiling the `.o` file with the right options. Deleting it and recompiling it won't fix that, unless he changes the options.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this with Informix.  Are these C modules that you are trying to call from a 4GL program and therefore need to combine them into a common  executable?

If so, just include all of your source modules in the compile directive.  Assuming c4gl, something like:

c4gl main.4gl others.4gl et5ibwqm0.c intfac_fl.c -o mainwithccalls.4ge

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was just a missing -m32 specifier which caused the compiler to reject one of the objects – user5586678